# NSbeep() on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Does `NSBeep()` exist on the iPhone? I just want to play a short error sound to indicate that the key pressed is not a legal character. I will play this in my textField delegate that dissalows the illegal characters.

Comment: I wouldn't use system sounds all together. They are but annoying - BEEP - Rather give the user a visual clue, like the screen flashing up for the fraction of a second or make the widget wiggle a bit, like when you mistype the password on os x.

Comment: I don't think error beeps as notification would be wise since people might often have their phones muted or earphones dangling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, NSBeep() is part of the ApplicationKit framework which doesn't exist on the iPhone.